# Sending map coordinates from phone to phone

Tags: google-maps, gps, real-time

We're creating a real-time GPS tracker app in IOS and Android. We want to see the real-time location of A from the map of B (like in UBER, I can see the location of the driver). We can now fetch the coordinates of A, but how should we send it to B in real-time also? Should we still use database to fetch and to send the coordinates? Or is there a way to send the coordinates from phone to phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need either a bi-directional data channel or a really fast no-sql database.

First, about bi-directional data channel. You can either use socket.io where you have a very simple node server to support the bi-directional data channel. Or you can just use WebRTC which is not exactly built for this purpose but you can still utilize the data channel to achieve your goal. However, either way it is done mostly using UDP connection, which, in other words, means it's not reliable. You cannot ensure that the other side receives the coordinates.

Second solution, a really fast no-sql database, on the other hand, might just align better with your app. If you are building a server from scratch, you still need socket.io to monitor the changes in your database and notify both sides (it won't be even near realtime if you use https requests). You can have them update coordinates under, for example, some reference like `/root/geolocation/{room-hash}/coords` and have both sides monitoring the same ref with socket.io connection.

If you are not looking for experience with building realtime server from scratch, and just want to finish your app. You can look into firebase which I think is a fairly fast database. You can use firebase library in your android/ios code. If you have already programmed your native code and don't want to change it. Use firebase cloud functions and make it api calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need a realtime communication mechanism to send A locations to B client. Something like websocket (ex: [socket.io](http://socket.io)) or some messaging protocol (ex: [MQTT.org](http://mqtt.org)) can help you.